# Android Facebook Unsupported post request error

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I am working on a Facebook application and am currently trying to have my app tag one of the user's friends.  I almost have it working 100%, except when it is supposed to be tagging the person, I instead get an error message that follows:

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

The user and photo IDs are for sure correct, that is not the issue.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what else could be causing this error.  Code is below for reference.  Thanks much!

```
public void setTag() {
    String relativePath = Constants.photoID + "/tags/" + Constants.userID;
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("x", "5");
    params.putString("y", "5");
    Constants.mAsyncRunner.request(relativePath, params, "POST", new TagPhotoRequestListener(),
            null);
}



public class TagPhotoRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

@Override
public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
    if (response.equals("true")) 
    {
        String message = "User tagged in photo at (5, 5)" + "\n";
        message += "Api Response: " + response;
        Log.i("TagPhotoRequestListener", message);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.w("TagPhotoRequestListener", "User could not be tagged.");
    }
}

public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    Log.w("TagPhotoRequestListener", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}

EDIT:  Here is my code for posting of a picture and getting the photoID.  For testing purposes it's just a single photo from my sdcard.

```
public void postPhoto() {
    byte[] data = null;

    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/Download/KathleenSchedule.jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, Constants.mFacebook.getAccessToken());
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(Constants.mFacebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
}


public class PhotoUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

@Override
public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
    try {
        // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
        Log.d("PhotoUploadListener", "Response: " + response.toString());
        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
        System.out.println(response);
        final String photo_id = json.getString("pid");
        Constants.photoID = photo_id;
```

Comment: Can you post the resulting string inside *relativePath*? Also, according to the docs you can post tags to *PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID* or *PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID*. Have you tried the later as well?

Comment: I just tried the later with no luck.  And the relativePath changes every run through of the application, in the application picture is uploaded and tagged after taking a new picture.  Here is an example of my most recent relativePath however:

100003703122664_62586/tags/100003702982567

Comment: Are you sure that this photo id is correct? It does not seem right. How do you get the id of the photo? That is, where is *Constants.photoID* coming from?

Comment: Ah I think you are right.  I am comparing my photoID to that from the Hackbook provided by Facebook.  In the Hackbook program they pulled the photoID by using json.getString("id") from their response.  I don't have a "id" in my response.  I have a "pid" (post-id which what I was using), "aid" (album id?), src, and I don't know if I have anything past that as it runs off the screen.

Comment: Response to what? I have no idea how you get the photo data.. Dont forget that all I know is what you wrote in your question. You need to provide more info if you want to get help.

Comment: Sorry about that, posted the photo code up above.  It's supposed to be final String photo_id = json.getString("id"), but my JSONObject doesn't contain that.  Thanks bud.

Comment: I just got it.  For some reason in my JSONObject I need to get "object_id".  It would be nice if Facebook actually updated their code of changes.  They have so many different methods of doing the same thing.  Thanks again

Comment: No, you just need to read the current, up to date documentation and not using deprecated methods, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now your problem is clear.

You are using the [photos.upload](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/) method which is deprecated:

> We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, so if you are
>   building a new application you shouldn't use this function. Instead
>   use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and POST to the photos connection of the [User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Because you are using an old method, you're getting and old response type.
Switch to using the graph api way, and you should get the photo id in the response.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I had thought I was using the Graph API.  Their documentation for Android is pretty poor in my opinion.  I'll have to see what the Graph API method is then.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you're missing something... The graph api has nothing to do with android, it's an api based on urls (http requests), and you can access it any way you want. The android sdk (much like the js or php ones) just wraps the http requests for you. For the documentation of the graph api check the Graph Api Documentation and not the Android SDK documentation.

Comment: Sure, and if this answers your problem, be sure to accept the answer.